# Pasar de un input a otro automaticamente

Tags: ionic, angular, entrada

Trabajando con ionic tengo tres inputs con 4 digitos cada uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando alguien ponga los primeros 4 numeros en el primer input pase automaticamente al siguiente input sin tener que usar tabindex, si alguien me pudiese guiar un poco se lo agradecería

Comment: Muestranos que tienes hasta ahora. StackOverflow es una comunidad de ayuda. Con preguntas así algunos pueden entender como si estas pidiendo que te hagan la tarea. Con mas información seguro podremos ayudarte :)

Comment: Lo siento, es mi primer dia en la comunidad, estoy probado con la funcion focus, si lo saco pongo como lo he hecho sino pongo el codigo que tengo hasta el momento

Answer (score 2):

Al final he podido lograr sacarlo con la ayuda de la funcion focus, dejo la solución, ojala salgan asi de rapido siempre los problemas

```
        <input type="text" placeholder="code"  maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input2.focus()" /> 

        <input type="text" id="input2" placeholder="code" maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) input3.focus()" /> 

        <input type="text" id="input3" placeholder="code" maxlength="4" onkeyup="if (this.value.length == this.getAttribute('maxlength')) " />
```